# Ruby - Equivalent to foreach

Tags: ruby, foreach, hashtable

I'm working on a project in RMXP with Ruby scripts.

I create a table with id maps. I am now looking to go the table such that if the player enters one of the maps of the table, things happen.

> Example of action: tMaps = [006, 008, 009]
>
> If the hero is on the map 004, 005 ... it nothing happens If the hero
>   is on the map 006, Action

I hope this is feasible. If not, what other means I have in Ruby to find the maps and to assign actions?

PS I've traveled a bit, this wiki : http://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programmation_Ruby/Contr%C3%B4le

Comment: Come again. Probably `[1,2,3].each` or `[1,2,3].select` or `[1,2,3].each` is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is wrong, I suppose you want integer : `[6, 8, 9]` not `[006, 008, 009]` (this is octal form)

```
tMaps = [6, 8, 9]

tMaps.each do
   |value| puts 'value : '+value.to_s
end

# or : 
for value in tMaps
   puts 'value : '+value.to_s
end
```

Comment: Yes, now I see a few more clear!

The second solution seems good. I test it in the afternoon and I see how that can happen.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Np. and if you want the comparaison, just add a `if <hero.current_map> == value then <action> end`
you can also mark this question as resolved if you have the solution. :]

Comment: I'll be a bit silly. How to solved? I did not find the button to do.

Comment: Sorry! I had not seen this symbol as an endorsement. The (solved) text would have been more meaningful.